# Calculating Tier 1 capital ratio SQL

Tags: sql

I have 4 GL accounts [gltable.acctno] with their current balance [gltable.cbal]

What SQL statement can I use to provide me with the sum of the following accounts:

79998 Total Equity Capital - (72100 Net Gain Loss on AFS Sec. - 72150 Net Gain Loss on HTM Sec. - 72200  Accum Other Comprehensive Income)

---

```
sample data >
 acctno 79998 with current balance of -17,603 
 acctno 72100 with current balance of 38,133 
 acctno 72150 with current balance of 0.00 
 acctno 72200 with current balance of 0.00
```

Can a SQL statement select these accounts and their values from current balance field and perform the formula
-17,603 - (38,133 - 0.00 - 0.00) = 55,736

```
my SQL

select acctno, cbal
from primary.gltable gltable
where acctno in (79998, 72100, 72150, 72200)

ACCTNO  CBAL
72100   38,133
72150   0
72200   0
79998   -17,603
```

Comment: How do you know what accno go to those accounts?

Comment: this is not clear -- can you give example data and expected results?

Comment: acctno 79998  cbal 17,603

Comment: ok so your table has two columns -- acctno and cbal?  and it has rows with those values in it?

Comment: Correct, I'm not sure how to request the values and then perform the calculation on the results.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Give what you have said the following should work.  I think there are other details of the data model that you are leaving out and this won't work.  However, since you are leaving them out I can only go by what you said.

```
SELECT TEC.cbal - (NGLAFS.cbal - NGLHTM.cbal - OTHER.cbal  )
FROM gltable AS TEC
LEFT JOIN gltable AS NGLAFS ON NGLAFS.acctno = 72100 
LEFT JOIN gltable AS NGLHTM ON NGLHTM.acctno = 72150 
LEFT JOIN gltable AS OTHER  ON OTHER.acctno = 72200 
WHERE TEC.acctno = 79998
```